# How to add Promotional Rule to the Orders Grid in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, orders, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I would like to show Promotional Rule applied or used for an order in the orders grid as a column in admin panel. How do I do this? please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Magento doesn't allow to do that out of the box. But you can create your own extension that will add the feature. And here is a brief explanation.

1. First of all, you have to add the rule name field to the orders grid collection. The better way is to do that using 'events'. In our case we need to observe '*sales_order_grid_collection_load_before*'. And here is the observer's method:

   ```
   /**
    * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
    * @return $this
    */
   public function prepareOrderGridCollection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
       $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();

       $orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
       $orderCollection->getSelect()
           ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
           ->columns(['order_id' => 'entity_id', 'coupon_rule_name']);

       $collection->getSelect()
           ->joinLeft(['order' => $orderCollection->getSelect()],
               'order.order_id = main_table.entity_id',
               ['coupon_rule_name']);

       return $this;
   }
   ```
2. After that, you need to add the new column to the orders grid block. For this, you can observe event '*core_layout_block_create_after*'. The observer's method:

   ```
   public function addColumnsToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
       $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

       if (!($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
           || $block->getNameInLayout() != 'sales_order.grid'
       ) {
           return $this;
       }

       $block->addColumnAfter('coupon_rule_name', [
           'header' => $block->__('Rule Name'),
           'index' => 'coupon_rule_name',
       ], 'shipping_name');

       return $this;
   }
   ```

That's it! Now the column should be added to the orders grid. Anyway, on my local machine ot works fine :)

**P.S.** Parts of the code were taken from our [Custom Order Grid](https://www.magestyapps.com/magento-extensions/custom-order-grid.html) extension.